# match all occurences of a word between 2 tags - regex

Tags: regex

I want to match all instances of a given word which is enclosed between 2 tags in a text

My regex:

```
(\[mytag\])(.*?)(mytext)(.*?)(\[\/mytag\])
```

Sample1:

```
[mytag]1 mytext xxx -- this one should match since its withing mytag [/mytag]
```

Sample2:

```
[mytag] something [/mytag]

2 mytext xxx -- THIS ONE SHOULD **NOT** MATCH - because its not actually within mytag!

[mytag] something [/mytag]
```

Sample3:

```
[mytag]4 mytext xxx -- this should match
xxxx xxx
xxxx
5 mytext -- this should match
xxx

[/mytag]
```

The regex I have works for Sample1.
Its incorrectly matching `mytext` in Sample2. It should not match.
Its matching only first instance of `mytext` in Sample3. I want to match all the instances.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: case 2 is working fine mytext is between the open close tag; for what you want you need to add condition to regex to not include your tag in string between; For case 3 It is also correct regex did find 1 mytext correctly between 2 tags

Comment: What regex engine/programming language are you using? Does it have look behind/ahead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to cross other `[mytag]` and `[/mytag]` in between, you can use

```
\[(mytag])(?:(?!\[/?\1).)*mytext(?:(?!\[/?\1).)*\[/\1
```

**Explanation**

- `\[` Match `[`
- `(mytag])` Capture group 1, match `mytag]`
- `(?:(?!\[/?\1).)*` Match any char not directly followed by `[`, optional `/` and a backreference to group 1 *(which is **mytag]**)*
- `mytext`
- `(?:(?!\[/?\1).)*` Again match any char not directly followed by `[`, optional `/` and a backreference to group 1
- `\[/\1` Match `[/` and a backreference to group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GjECDK/1)

Note that if the delimiter is not `/`, you don't have to escape the forward slash.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet using JavaScript (without lookahead or lookback):

```js
// ===== test data =======================================

const text=`Sample1:
[mytag]1 mytext xxx -- this one [b]should[/b] match since its within mytag [/mytag]

Sample2:
[mytag] something [/mytag]

2 mytext xxx -- THIS ONE SHOULD **NOT** MATCH - because its not actually within mytag!

[mytag] something [/mytag]
Sample3:

[othertag]4 mytext xxx -- this should match
xxxx xxx
xxxx
5 mytext -- this should match
xxx
[/othertag]`;

// ===== solution starts here: ============================

const regexp=/\[([a-z]+])([\w\W\n]*?)\[\/\1/gi;
let r,matchedtext=[];
while (r=regexp.exec(text)) matchedtext.push(r[2]);
console.log(matchedtext.join("\n"));
```

In my regular expression I capture any possible tag name and look for matching pairs. Note that this will always capture the contents of the *outer tag* in case there are nested constructs.

The second pattern group `([\w\W\n]*?)` is the one I collect in the while loop further down. It matches anything (including newlines!) that could appear between two matching tags in a *non-greedy* way (`?`). This will avoid merging several tags with the same tag name into one.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your existing regular expression to work for any tag.. not just `mytag`. This way, you won't have to check for opening and closing tags.

```
\[(\w+)\](.*?)(mytext)(.*?)\[\/\1\]
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex will solve your issue

```
^\s*(\[mytag\])(.*?\s*)(mytext)(.*?\s*)+(\[\/mytag\]).*
```

Now capture Group3 for desire text.